# How to disable user interaction in a custom View

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a custom View `NSView` and I want to disable userinteraction, but I'm not sure how to do this.

My idea was:

```
[myView setEnabled:NO];
```

but it's wrong and doesn't work. How can I make it so that, it's just visible for the user, and nothing else?

Comment: try [myView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Comment: @CodersParadise: this question is about OS X, not iOS. There is no such property or method on `NSView`...

Answer (score 16):

NSView doesn't have either setEnabled: or setIgnoresMouseEvents:

Implement [the `hitTest:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/hitTest%3a) to return `nil`.

Comment: I like this solution. Simple to implement and way more robust and reliable than disabling the subviews if they are controls.

Comment: This did not work for me at all. Implementing mouseDown: that does nothing is the solution in my case.

Comment: That would prevent mouse interactions but we'd want to disable any interaction, including via the keyboard (which is possible by enabling keyboard navigation with ctrl-F7, then using the Tab and space keys)

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/71931-setenabled-on-nsview.html):

```
//
//  NSView-DisableSubsAdditions.m
//  Can Combine Icons
//
//  Created by David Remahl on Tue Dec 25 2001.
//  Copyright (c) 2001 Infinity-to-the-Power-of-Infinity. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NSView-DisableSubsAdditions.h"

@implementation NSView(DisableSubsAdditions)

- (void)disableSubViews
{
    [self setSubViewsEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)enableSubViews
{
    [self setSubViewsEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)setSubViewsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    NSView* currentView = NULL;
    NSEnumerator* viewEnumerator = [[self subviews] objectEnumerator];

    while( currentView = [viewEnumerator nextObject] )
    {
        if( [currentView respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)] )
        {
            [(NSControl*)currentView setEnabled:enabled];
        }
        [currentView setSubViewsEnabled:enabled];

        [currentView display];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Copyrighted code pasted on stack overflow? For real!?

Comment: @wcochran That's actually permitted. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319061/2228559

Comment: Here's another library similar to this answer: https://github.com/ardalahmet/DisableSubviews

Answer (score 3):

subclass the `NSView` and add following method

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{

}
```

Comment: Perfect. hitTest: returning nil does not work for me at all - it seemed to prevent mouseDown being invoked. So just use an empty mouseDown:

Comment: That would prevent mouse interactions but we'd want to disable any interaction, including via the keyboard (which is possible by enabling keyboard navigation with ctrl-F7, then using the Tab and space keys)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example in Swift 4. Place your views into this custom view.

```
class UserInterectionDisabledView: NSView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: That might prevent mouse interactions but we'd want to disable any interaction, including via the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think overriding `hitTest(_:)` is not ideal as it can block all interactions behind it.

A better way is to make the view refuse to `becomeFirstResponder`. So that events can be send to next responder, basically it skips the view.

```swift
class SubclassNSView: NSView {

  public var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool = true

  open override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    if isUserInteractionEnabled == false {
      return false
    } else {
      return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solutions here didn't work for me: as someone mentioned, the keyboard interaction are not disabled, and the like issues. Additionally, my custom view changed the mouse cursor to the hand icon, showing intractability, even if interaction was disabled via one of the approaches.

I ended up removing the view and adding it back later. Since I just drew an opaque layer on top of my custom view, I didn't need to display anything. So removing it (and adding it back when needed) worked better.