# Incorrect NSCursor originating from background NSView

Tags: cocoa

I wanted to change the cursor in my cocoa application. I've followed the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266513/1229237), with success.

I have an `NSView`, let's call it `NSViewA`, behind another `NSView`, `NSViewB`. `NSViewA` contains a subclassed `NSButton` where the cursor has been changed. `NSViewA` and `NSViewB` have the same superview. So something like this:

```
- NSWindow
    - NSViewA
        - NSButtonSubclass
    - NSViewB
```

My problem is that when `NSViewB` is shown, and the cursor is ontop of `NSViewB`, but in the same x y coordinates of the `NSButton` behind `NSViewB`, the cursor changes to that specified in the `NSButton` subclass.

How do I stop this behaviour?

The reason for this layout is that I'm creating a 'lightbox' control. If you think something along the lines of the `NSWindow` greying out, and a centred box appearing showing an error message. That sort of thing.

I previously had a problem where you could still click buttons, etc, behind `NSViewB`. This was solved by suppressing `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:`. I've tried doing something similar with other mouse-related events, such as `mouseEntered:` and `mouseExited:` with no luck.

Comment: So NSViewB does not entirely cover NSViewA?

Comment: @Max `NSViewB` is the same size and is in front of `NSViewA`, and they both fill the `NSWindow`. `NSViewB` is only visible when I need to show a message. When it's visible, it does cover all of `NSViewA`. `NSViewB` is the semi-transparent dark overlay covering the `NSWindow`, which contains a child `NSView` which is my custom message box. `NSViewA` is the 'root' view containing all the UI for my app.

Comment: Therefore you can't just hide NSViewA?

Comment: @Max correct. Although `NSViewB` does cover all of `NSViewA`, parts of `NSViewA` can still be seen through the semi-transparent section of `NSViewB`, albeit they appear faded due to the overlay. It's only `NSViewB`'s child `NSView` (smaller and centred) which visually hides the content from `NSViewA`.

Comment: After posting my answer I began to wonder why you couldn't just use a new temporary``NSWindow`` to do the job of ``viewB``. This is a much more Cocoa-like solution in that sheets and modal alert dialogs are windows, and your ``viewB`` is doing much the same job as they do in native apps. Plus you don't have to change the behaviour of ``viewA`` in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make the addition of your custom cursor rectangle contingent on the `enabled` status of your button? In other words, your `resetCursorRects` would look like this:

```
// MyButton.swift
override func resetCursorRects() {
    if enabled {
        addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: NSCursor.pointingHandCursor())
    }
}
```

Whenever `viewB` is about to be shown, disable the button, and call for the rects belonging to your button to be invalidated. If you're using Swift, you could do this second bit in a property observer attached to the `enabled` property itself:

```
// MyButton.swift
override var enabled: Bool {
    didSet {
        window!.invalidateCursorRectsForView(self)
    }
}
```

If you don't want your button to take on a *disabled* look, make the `addCursorRect` call contingent on some other flag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My example above is simplified, as in reality I have quite a few places where the cursor has changed, in various subviews of `NSViewA`, and not just on some `NSButton`s. I'm hoping this can work with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11740823/1229237). I'm going to give it a try a little later. I'm still quite new to cocoa, with mainly a .NET background.