# Disable NSButton without grayed image

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I want to disable the user interaction of `NSButton`. The only possible option seems to be setting `isEnabled` to false:

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

...but the problem is that it's giving a white shade to the image of my button. Is there any way to get rid of that shade?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set the `imageDimsWhenDisabled` property of the corresponding button cell:

```
button.isEnabled = false
if let cell = button.cell as? NSButtonCell {
    cell.imageDimsWhenDisabled = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be instead of disabling it you can let it fire and handle it accordingly in code. such as do nothing when condition to disable applies.

Comment: There is more than one button overlapping. I need to disable one type of buttons otherwise it will eat the touch event of the button behind. Can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861677/3151675) says, override `NSButton` and return nil for `hitTest(_:)`.

If you want to toggle whether user interaction is enabled, create a custom variable and return `super.hitTest(point)` if you want the button to be enabled.

```
class CustomButton: NSButton {
    var isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
        return isUserInteractionEnabled ? super.hitTest(point) : nil
    }
}
```